# How to set Firebase Messaging only to one flavour of my app?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've created a `google-service.json` file specifically for one the flavors of my app, and put that file in the correct directory of that specific flavor. Now, when I try to run the project I get `No matching client found for package name (Google Analytics) - multiple productFlavors & buildTypes` error. I want only one flavor to receive messages from firebase, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To allow FCM to only specific flavor, change your gradle file as following:

```
if (getGradle().getStartParameter().getTaskRequests().toString().contains("flavor_name"))
{ 
    // run this plugin only for "flavor_name" flavor
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a more elegant way:

```
        remoteFCM {
             dimension "pushtechnology"
             applicationIdSuffix ".remoteFCM"
             versionNameSuffix "-remoteFCM"
             // Apply only for this flavor
             apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
        }
```

remoteFCM is the flavor defined in the build.gradle(:app) file and the only flavor which uses this plugin.